# OpenLayers does not appear in the QGIS plugin menu

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, osx

I have installed the [OpenLayers QGIS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/), which features external map layers in QGIS. Quoting the official page:

> OpenStreetMap, Google Maps, Bing Maps layers and more

In QGIS, it seems that the plugin is well installed:

[image]

However, no new items were added to the <kbd>plugin</kbd> menu:

[image]

Any idea how to start the plugin? I have tried restarting QGIS and reinstalling the plugin several times, with no success.