# Web menu not shown in QGIS 2.8.2

Tags: openlayers-2, qgis-2.8

I have looked at [the first answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121085/where-is-the-openlayers-plugin-in-qgis-2-6) and the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113809/openlayers-does-not-appear-in-the-qgis-plugin-menu) and I'm on *QGIS 2.8.2* (Ubuntu 14.04) but the **Web** menu doesn't appear even if OpenLayers plugin is shown to be in the Installed plugins.

[image]
Where can get the OpenLayers plugin to show off ?

Comment: Could you right-click on the top toolbar and see if you can check the **Web** menu from there to enable it?

Comment: Did you enable the plugin in the plugin manager?

Comment: I did all you have proposed but I wasn't getting the 'Web'menu. See below the radical solution I end up using : complete reinstall.

Comment: I also have this issue on 2.8.2-Wien with openlayers plugin installed. Once I install QuickOSM plugin on top and restart QGIS, the Web menu disappears. After uninstalling QuickOSM and restarting QGIS, the Web menu re-appears!

This may be language specific: QGIS is running in German, OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I have English as my language, so it may not be a language specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved it by reinstalling QGIS i.e `sudo apt-get autoremove qgis` and `rm -rf ~/.qgis2/` and  `sudo apt-get autoclean`.

Then I reinstalled it by `sudo apt-get install qgis`. And then install the **OpenLayers** plugin.  Now I have the **Web** menu.